# How can I center a map around a pin in my app?

Tags: maui

I'm trying to add a map to my MAUI app view.

View:

```xml
<Map HeightRequest="500" ItemsSource="{Binding Pins}">
    <Map.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Pin Location="{Binding Location}"
                 Address="{Binding Address}"
                 Label="{Binding Label}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Map.ItemTemplate>
</Map>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
var pin = new Pin { Location = new Location(51, 0), Label = "Here" };
Pins = new List<Pin> { pin };
Map.Pins.Add(pin);
```

This adds a pin just fine, but I want to centre the map around the pin.

I thought I would be able to bind to a Map object in the ViewModel, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

I tried binding but there don't seem to be properties to bind to for setting the default view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, not was I was expecting to have to do but it works.

https://dev.to/icebeam7/bindableobject-behaviors-to-enhance-mvvm-in-net-maui-maps-3je9

Basically this article shows you how to create a `BindableBehavior<T>` object and use it to create a `MapBehavior`.

Then an ObservableProperty can be added to the ViewModel for the 'places' you want to `pin`.

```
[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<Place> bindablePlaces;
```

In the view you'll need something like this:

```
<maps:Map ...>
   <maps:Map.Behaviors>
       <behaviors:MapBehavior 
           IsReady="{Binding IsReady}"
           Places="{Binding BindablePlaces}"/>
   </maps:Map.Behaviors>
</maps:Map>
```

Check out the article for more info.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map)

> These properties, with the exception of the MapElements, Pins, and
> VisibleRegion properties, are backed by BindableProperty objects,
> which mean they can be targets of data bindings.

You will need to set the `VisibleRegion` from the code behind

Comment: I cant set VisibleRegion. It's a read only property.

Comment: I also want to bind the Map in the view to the map object in the view model.

Comment: Use `MoveToRegion`

Comment: I think I still need to bind the viewmodel `map` to the view `map`. not sure how to do that.

Comment: You are already binding the Pins to the VM.  I’m not sure what else you want to bind.  Please be specific about what you are trunk to do

Comment: I'm not sure I can get more specific. I have a map object in the view model its a `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map` and I want to bind it to the view models Map which is also a `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map`. But there is no property to bind the two together. I can bind properties from a view model to a view, but cant bind an object (Map) to the views Map. Maybe I'm not understanding something.

Comment: Sorry, as noted in the docs Pins is not bindable.  I originally thought that it was